Finding positive integer solutions for $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt y}=\frac{5}{6}$
I've tried to solve for x and y being positive integers in this equation: $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt y}=\frac{5}{6}$. I tried this approach but it didn't work: Let $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ then $a^{2}=\frac{1}{x}$ which means that $x=\frac{1}{a^{2}}$ and since x is an a positive integer ${a^{2}}$ should divide 1 which implies that $a^{2}=1$ so $a=1$ hence $x=1$. But when substituting the obtained value of $x$ in the given equation we conclude that $\frac{1}{\sqrt y}=\frac{-1}{6}$ which is impossible. So i would gladly like any help to correct my approach and to find the solution.

Well, a search seems indicated.  If $z≥6$ then $\frac 1{\sqrt z}<\frac 5{12}$ so if both $x,y≥6$ the equation is impossible.  That kind of limits the search...

$a^2 = \frac{1}{x}$ is not an integer (for $x\ne 1$), so you shouldn't talk about divisibility involving $a^2$.

You could first solve $\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{v}=\frac{5}{6}$, e.g., $u=2$, $v=3$. This gives $x=4$ and $y=9$.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the roughly similar How many ordered pairs $(x,y)$ are there such that ${1\over\sqrt x}+{1\over\sqrt y}={1\over\sqrt {20}}$, where both $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

Bill, your equation is equivalent to$$\left(5\sqrt x-6\right)\left(5\sqrt y-6\right)=36$$

How did you facrorize the expression?

Bill, it is very easy to factorise it: intelligenti pauca.

Assume $x\geq y$ then $${1\over \sqrt{y}} \geq  {1\over \sqrt{x}}$$ so $${2\over \sqrt{y}} \geq  {1\over \sqrt{x}}+{1\over \sqrt{y}} = {5\over 6}\implies y\leq {144\over 25}\implies y\leq 5$$
The rest is easy.
